# how to check how many invalid fields are left on each validation fix in jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am displaying all of my errors in a div and want to hide div automatically when I fix all of my errors. I want it to happen before click on submit.

For example I have two input boxes and on submit I got required errors in a div then I start filling one by one when I fill that last input box I want my errorsDiv fade of without clicking on submit.

```
$(function(){
  $.validator.setDefaults({
  highlight: function(element)
  {
    $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-invalid');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element)
  {
    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');

      ====== This is it what I was trying ======

       var allErrors = $(".error");
       if(allErrors.length < 1)
        {
        $(".errorsDiv").fadeOut();
        }
      ========================================
   },
  });
  var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate({

    rules:{
      hotel_name:{
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true,
      },
      hotel_country:{
        required: true
      }        
    },
    messages:{
      hotel_name:{
        required: "Please enter hotel name",
        lettersonly: "Only letters A to Z are allowed",
      },
      hotel_country:{
        required: "Please choose hotel country",
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         $("#errorsDiv").fadeIn();
         error.appendTo('#errorsDiv');
       },
     errorElement: 'span',
     wrapper: 'li'

  });


  });
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any logic to remove the individual errors from the `#errorsDiv` container

Comment: I try that in unhighlight: function above in code section